# Significance of covariates in mixed model analysis

Tags: mixed-model, stepwise-regression, predictor, forward-backward

I have a question about the significance of adding covariates in a mixed model that I can't explain, or find an answer for online. I hope that by posting my question here, someone may know a good explanation.

I am using a linear mixed model approach in SPSS to find significant predictors for EQ5D in time. I am trying to use a forward step-wise procedure, however there is no forward step-wise option implemented for linear mixed models in SPSS. For this reason I use the difference in the -2 restricted log likelihood of two models as a Chi square value with df as the sum of the Numerator df.

In an exploratory analysis I have found that the covariate 'treatment' is the strongest predictor in time, and 'ECOG_dich' is the strongest time-independent predictor. Both covariates are dichotomous (0 or 1). 'ECOG_dich' has shown to have no effect in time according to mixed model analysis, and plotting ECOG_dich = 0 vs ECOG_dich = 1 shows two times almost exactly the same trends.

Since I am interested in treatment effects (because of my research question), I start my base-model with treatment, and try to see what may happen if 'ECOG_dich' is added.

`MIXED EQ5D BY time treatment
  /CRITERIA=CIN(95) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0, 
    ABSOLUTE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0.000001, ABSOLUTE)
  /FIXED=time treatment time*treatment | SSTYPE(3)
  /METHOD=REML
  /PRINT=CPS DESCRIPTIVES  SOLUTION.`

For my base model I find a -2 Restricted Log Likelihood of -335.540 (df = 8), with 'time*treatment' as only significant covariate.

If I than add 'ECOG_dich' without and with time:

```
MIXED EQ5D BY time treatment ECOG_dich
      /CRITERIA=CIN(95) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0, 
        ABSOLUTE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0.000001, ABSOLUTE)
      /FIXED=time treatment ECOG_dich time*treatment | SSTYPE(3)
      /METHOD=REML
      /PRINT=CPS DESCRIPTIVES  SOLUTION.

MIXED EQ5D BY time treatment ECOG_dich
      /CRITERIA=CIN(95) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0, 
        ABSOLUTE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0.000001, ABSOLUTE)
      /FIXED=time treatment ECOG_dich time*treatment time*ECOG_dich | SSTYPE(3)
      /METHOD=REML
      /PRINT=CPS DESCRIPTIVES  SOLUTION.
```

As a function this would resemble the function y= β0 + β1 * time + β2 * treatment + β3 * ECOG_dich + β4 * time * treatment + β5 * time * ECOG_dich.

Time can have values 0, 1, 2, or 3 and ECOG_dich and treamtment are either 0 or 1. The difference in log likelihood is caused by adding β3 and β5 * ECOG_dich to the model. I can also add a random effect per patient, which does not have a big effect on my results (and my question).

I find a -2 Restricted Log Likelihood of -337.364698 (df = 9) for the base-model with ECOG_dich and a -2 Restricted Log Likelihood of -325.703498 (df = 12) for the base-model with ECOG_dich and ECOG_dich*time.

(-335.540 - -325.703498) is significant whereas (-335.540 - -337.364698) is not according to my calculations. Therefore it seems that adding a significant covariate to my base model has a insignificant effect on the -2 Restricted Log Likelihood. However, when adding the same covariate in time (which is insignificant by itself), seems to result in a significant change in the -2 Restricted Log Likelihood.

This seems very odd to me, and me and my colleagues have no explanation for this. Therefore I would like to ask:

1. Is my procedure correct?
2. Is there any other explanation why I find a significant outcome for ECOG_dich*time?
3. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve on my methods here?

Comment: Can you write out the equations for the models you fitted so that those of us who are not SPSS users don't have to trudge through the code to see what you fitted?

Comment: How did the significance of each of your parameters change with the addition of new variables into the model?  Can you post some output here?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is a linear mixed model with fixed effects shown as /FIXED= ... and random effects shown as /RANDOM= ... Random effects are missing here in the syntax, I added them later, but this did not alter my solutions much. I have no idea how SPSS syntax is turned into equations. I will try to post some output below.

Comment: Null Model:
/FIXED=time /RANDOM=ID
df = 5 -2 Restricted Log Likelihood -368.079
time sig. = .000

Alternative Model 1:
/FIXED=time ECOG_dich /RANDOM=ID
df = 6 -2 Restricted Log Likelihood -365.025
time sig. = .000 ECOG_dich sig. = .164

Alternative Model 2:
/FIXED=time ECOG_dich ECOG_dich*time /RANDOM=ID
df = 9 -2 Restricted Log Likelihood -358.853
time sig. = .000 ECOG_dich sig. = .239 ECOG*time sig. .057

Comment: I meant for you to write what you are fitting as an equation in $y=\beta_0+\beta_1X_{1ij}+...+\beta_nX_{nij}$ using the appropriate index subscripts (i.e., i, j, etc.).  Please edit your post to include the additional information you provided in the comments, so that everything is in one place

Comment: I have updated my question, and hope that everying is clear now. The way that SPSS works is not entirly clear to me, because I have not been able to access the code within its libaries/packages.